# Android writing int values to file

Tags: android, int, fileoutputstream

I have trouble writing int values to a file in my app. When I write strings to file,its doing great. I tried int values using ObjectOutputStream but only some weird symbols(group of them not even one) keep appearing. So I tried using DataOutputStream too but even that doesn't work. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);    
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile,true);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

private boolean checkAnswer() 
{
    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feditText);
    String answer = edit.getText().toString();
    if(answer.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter solution before moving on to next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        int qno = f.getQno();
        //ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            //oos.writeObject(new Integer(qno));
        dos.writeInt(qno);
        dos.writeBytes(answer);
        dos.writeBytes(eol);//eol line separator already declared 
        dos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

    return true;
}
```

So everything else in the above code is doing fine...only int values are putting up a fight..So can anyone help me?? 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: An `int` is stored as a 4 byte value, not as a decimal representation.

Comment: I tried writing it as object or bytes...Can you tell me where did I try writing it in decimal representation?

Comment: Thats right, it sounds like it is working correctly. Why do you think there is a problem? If you need a string representation of the integer, just convert it to a string. But then why use DataOutputStream?

Comment: @Greg First tried objectoutputstream didn't work...later I did some browsing and saw an example using dataoutputstream..So I tried using it..no errors nothing in both the cases..I don't understand where the problem is..I just want the integer value to appear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataOutputStream` is not supposed to write textual files. Instead you use it to convert the standard java primitive type to bytes, therefore writing it compactly.

This results in a binary file, which you are **not supposed to read**.

If you want to read it, you would have to format the number as text (e.g. `Integer.toString`). The disadvantage is that this can require signifantly more space, depending on the value and the base.

Formatted in decimal as `2147483647` it would require 10 byte, whilst in binary it would constantly consume 4 byte. Note that values with only three digits require less space.

You *could* use the DataOutputStream to write the number in textform:

```
dos.writeBytes(Integer.toString(yourNumber));
```

If you really want to write a text file, you should use the [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
writer.write("Whatever text.");
writer.write(Integer.toString(42));
writer.newLine();
writer.close();
```

If you wan't to parse it, you probably want to have a look at [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

However, from guessing what you wan't to do, that might be what you need.
I guess you want to store the state of your quiz-like app, in this case the answers.

There are numerous easier ways to achieve that:

- [Serialization](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html)

  - You can use the standard, if it doesn't prove too slow
- Writing the file in binary

  - Should be easier because of the fixed length of primitive values, using `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: No, use the [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

Comment: It is dos.write().. otherwise it gives an error saying "the method writeBytes(String) in the type DataOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])"...Can you change it, please..it would help others...thank you..

Comment: @user2784307: Take another look at that example... The error hints that you try to use the DataOutputStream, which you shouldn't if you want a text-file. But look at my edited post...

Comment: I tried that dos.writeBytes(Integer.toString(yourNumber).getBytes("UTF-8"));.. it gave the error I mentioned..So I changed it to dos.write() and it worked absolutely fine...